# Knockout custom binding, Identify Update is called by changes and not in initially

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I am doing an Ajax call in the custom binding `update`. As per the documentation, `update` is called initially as well as when you update. I don't want my ajax calls to get fired in the initial case.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.RadioB = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContent) {
        var switchValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (switchValue)
            $(element).bootstrapToggle('on');
        else
            $(element).bootstrapToggle('off');

        if (!viewModel.Enable())
            $(element).bootstrapToggle('disable')

        $(element).on('change', function () {
            valueAccessor()($(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var handleToggle = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor)().RadioBChange.handleToggle;
        //handleToggle(viewModel, $(element).attr("name")); // AJAX CALL
    }
}
```

I know there is a workaround to attach a change event but is there any other way to idetify it so that I can avoid calls initially?

Comment: @adiga: I have gone through this. As I mentioned, there is a workaround, just to check if there is any standard way which is now available

Comment: @adiga: anyway will make it as duplicate :)

Comment: okay. Could've waited to see if anybody has a better solution before closing it.

Comment: You could also create an observable subscription in the init function and call your ajax from there.